# how do I convert a mysql query to a php query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been running this query on my mysql database:

```
select email from main where phno=1234567890
```

and it returns this (http://i.imgur.com/YiVQ4NN.png)

So here was my attempt in php:

```
$search_query="select email from main where phno = 5756407850";
$to = mysql_query($search_query);
echo "hello " . mysql_query($search_query);`
```

and my result in the web browser is `hello Resource id #34`

How could I extract just whats in the email part? In this case just the "HGH" string?

Answer:

```
$search_query="select email from main where phno = 5756407850";
$result = mysql_query($search_query);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$to = $array[0];
echo "hello " . $to;
```

Comment: How about you peruse the fine manual for starters? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php Also don't miss http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$to will just contain the resultset object from your query.

You should split it into an array using mysql_fetch_array and use the 0th element, or use the mysql_result command to pull the 0th element from $to

Details on these here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

However, this methodology is deprecated...you should look at PDO as the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_query="select email from main where phno = 5756407850";
$to = mysql_query($search_query);
echo "hello " . mysql_query($search_query);`
```

you already assigned this mysql_query($search_query) into the variable $to why not use that instead, and you cant just echo the results directly you have iterate through the results you have to use fetch_assoc or fetch_array, btw welcome fellow new member.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$search_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM main WHERE phno='5756407850'");

//do simple count check in your database
$count = mysql_num_rows($search_query); 
//if the count is greater than 0; if there is a match
if($count > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_query)){
$to = $row["phno"];/*this here will grab the number in a variable*/


}//end while statement
}//end if statement


//will echo the variable that has the number in it onto the php page
echo $to; 
?>
```

try the above code, 
Sorry, I found your question a little hard to understand/different to what I do, but that should work for you.

usually when people want to grab someones details from a database using php they will first make a query that lists all entries to that database on a separate page for a user to select from, then they will make this query on the next page

```
("SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE selected_id='$selected_id');
```

then grab all the data from that table and put them into php variables, and echo it out

if I'm not making much sense, then by all means I highly recommend http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006303.do as it does really teach php and mysql in a very very easy to understand way

Comment: I'd like to add the book i recommended also uses "mysqli" instead of mysql queries.. Which is important, because everyone has a beef if the use "mysql" queries, and it is important to use "mysqli" in this day